# How can I tell which TcxGrid row the user dropped something onto?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, devexpress, tcxgrid

The user is dragging something over my TcxGrid component. How can I know which row it gets dropped on?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question doesn't make sense

Comment: Not everyone's first language is English :(

Comment: @Despatcher That is true. The question still doesn't make sense though!!

Comment: Thanks Rob, my English is not good enough, I am learning it

Comment: Albeit the description is not very detailed, the question makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example located on the DevExpress site for a drag and drop inside a cxGrid. I used the same technic to implement a drag and drop between two cxGrids.

[How to implement drag-and-drop inside a Grid](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A461.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this example solved my problem, the GridRecord is what I looked for:
    HT := ViewInfo.GetHitTest(X, Y);
    ReorderRows(TcxGridTableView(GridView), TcxGridRecordCellHitTest(HT).GridRecord);

Answer (score 1):

You Should get some feedback from the drop event or use the Mouse up event then get the grid co-ordinates from the X,Y positions using on one the many Dev express calls. I think, off-hand.